# Using an existing entity framework class library with MVC WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a class library which contains all of my Entity Framework code.

In a standard ASP.NET Project I can reference this DLL and start using the classes and interact with my database right out of the box.

However, I am now starting to build a new Web API using the new [ASP.NET MVC Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). I would like to be able to use this existing library in this new API, though I am unsure how to wire it up. Is this something that's possible? Or should I re-produce the entity set for this project?

I have limited experience with MVC and have built only a small portfolio with it, and that site had all new models and entities etc.

I tried adding a controller and selecting Model class from my entity library and also Data Context Class, though received an "Unsupported context type" message.

If it helps, I can add the code for the entity library as a separate project to my solution, rather than just the DLL, though I would like to make minimal changes to this as other projects utilize the same framework.

**Update**

I know I can use the DbContext generator to generate all the dbContext classes for the EF entities, though I'm wondering if there is another way so I don't have to add the EF files directly into this project too.

Comment: What is the base type of your context class?

Comment: I built it all using the designer (*.edmx) - Assume that would be the ObjectContext class?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recipe we have settled upon for each of our systems that stands us in good stead.

Projects:

SQL Server Project for deployment purposes.
EDM Project to hold the EF Model and Data context with no code generation.
Entities/POCO project with T4 Templates to auto generate the classes from the EDM.

The WCF Service solution holds all three of the above projects plus the WCF Service Project itself, has access to the data context and exposes objects to any UI layers in a controlled manner.

The UI also holds the Entities/POCO project and a reference to the Service in the UI project itself, with the Service Reference reusing types in that Entities project assembly.

Benefits:

1. Almost no duplication.
2. Rapid maintainability and sustainability.
3. Separation of concerns.
4. Scalability baked in via Net Tcp Service.

So to summarise, I wouldn't use a DLL reference, I would use an Entity/Poco project as your intermediary, included in both ends of your application delivery.

I hope this is of some help.